# How to conver files from .tex to .docx while keep the itatic math symbols?

Tags: ms-word, latex, pandoc

I'm using `\bm` to set the itatic math symbols in latex.
Now, I need to convert my latex files to docx files.

But I found that `pandoc` only uses the default `Cambria Math` font.
And there are two problems:

- The orginial boldfaced Latex math symbols are not itatic anymore.
- How to change the math font in `pandoc` terminal command?

Exampl: demo.tex

```
\begin{equation}
    \underset{f_t(\cdot)}{argmin}: \mathcal{R}=E\left[\mathcal{L}\left(f_t\left(\bm{X}_t \mid \bm{X}_s, \bm{Y}_s^{c}, {\bm{\theta}}, \bm{H}_{A}, \bm{Y}_s^{n}\right), \bm{Y}_t\right)\right]
    \label{eq:ALDBT_risk}
\end{equation}
```

My `pandoc` command is as follows:

```
pandoc demo.tex -o demo.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a direct solution by Pandoc.

As an alternative, we may use MathType.

If we want to use `Latin Mordern Math`, we may refer to this [post](https://blog.csdn.net/caoxiong_tju/article/details/89740877).

Then define Bold/Itatic for matrices/vectors in MathType/formatting/Definition/.[image] as illusrated in Figure 1.

Finally, conduct step 1 and step 2 as illusrated in Figure 2, sequentially

[image]